# How to call a static string using loops from another java class

Tags: java

i have two java class under same project  **Cf.java
and CommonData.java**

In general if i need to cal a static String (say p1 )from CommonData.java, i can do it by typing the below statement in Cf.class

```
 String needed_string = CommonData.p1;
```

i have many values like p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6. The logic used below doesnt work. pls help me in alternative solution

```
int counter;

for(counter=0;counter<=6;counter++)
{
String needed_string = CommonData.p(counter);

}
```

Comment: Wrong tag. Javascript **IS NOT** Java.

Comment: If you think `CommonData.p(count)` will become p1, p2, p3... that is _not_ how this will work.

Comment: What is p(count) ? Post the method.

Comment: Use an array: `static String[] p = {"your", "strings"};` and address them like `CommonData.p[count]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you populate a String[] with the common data, and then use your for loop?

```
String[] commonData = {CommonData.p1, CommonData.p2,.........};
int counter;

for(counter=0;counter<=6;counter++)
{
String needed_string = commonData[counter];

}
```

Comment: Thank yu!!. Though it took time to bring in all values inside an array, My target was achieved.....